# orientdb - error on import csv - admin credentials

Tags: orientdb

I trie import and edge by oetl with orientdb 2.2.4/2.2.5/2.2.6. In all versions the error is the same. If I use version 2.1 the error doesn't occurs.

My json file is

```
    {
    "config": {
      "log": "info",
              "parallel": false
    },
    "source": {
      "file": {
        "path": "/opt/orientdb/csvs_1milhao/metodo03/a10a.csv"
      }
    },
    "extractor": {
      "row": {
      }
    },
    "transformers": [{
      "csv": {
        "separator": ",",
        "columnsOnFirstLine": true,
        "columns": ["psq_id_from:integer",
        "pro_id_to:integer",
        "ordem:integer"]
      }
    },
    {
      "command": {
        "command": "create edge PUBLICOU from (SELECT FROM index:Pesquisador.psq_id WHERE key = ${input.psq_id_from}) to   (SELECT FROM index:Producao.pro_id where key = ${input.pro_id_to})",
        "output": "edge"
      }
    }],
    "loader": {
      "orientdb": {
        "dbURL": "remote:localhost/dbUmMilhaoM03", 
        "dbUser": "admin",
        "dbPassword": "admin",
        "dbURL": "remote:localhost/dbUmMilhaoM03", 
        "dbType": "graph",
        "standardElementConstraints": false,
        "batchCommit": 1000,
        "classes": [{
            "name": "PUBLICOU",
            "extends": "E"
        }]
      }
    }
}
```

When I execute the oetl command, the result is:

```
        root@teste:/opt/orientdb_226/bin# ./oetl.sh /opt/orientdb_226/scripts_orientdb/Db1Milhao/metodo03/a10a_psq_publicou_pro.json >> log_m03
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException: Error on creating ETL processor
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.parse(OETLProcessor.java:225)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.parse(OETLProcessor.java:176)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.parseConfigAndParameters(OETLProcessor.java:144)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.main(OETLProcessor.java:108)
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.loader.OLoaderException: unable to manage remote db without server admin credentials
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.loader.OOrientDBLoader.manageRemoteDatabase(OOrientDBLoader.java:447)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.loader.OOrientDBLoader.configure(OOrientDBLoader.java:391)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.configureComponent(OETLProcessor.java:448)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.configureLoader(OETLProcessor.java:262)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.parse(OETLProcessor.java:209)
    ... 3 more
```

When I execute with OrientDb 2.1 the result is:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessHaltedException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Source vertex '#-1:-1' not exists
```

But the indexes exists

```
 Name   Type    Class   Properties  Engine  Actions
Atuacao.atu_id  UNIQUE  Atuacao     [atu_id]    SBTREE  
dictionary  DICTIONARY      [undefined]     SBTREE  
Instituicao.ins_id  UNIQUE  Instituicao     [ins_id]    SBTREE  
ORole.name  UNIQUE  ORole   [name]  SBTREE  
OUser.name  UNIQUE  OUser   [name]  SBTREE  
Pais.pai_id     UNIQUE  Pais    [pai_id]    SBTREE  
Pesquisador.psq_id  UNIQUE  Pesquisador     [psq_id]    SBTREE  
Producao.pro_id     UNIQUE  Producao    [pro_id]    SBTREE  
Publicacao.pub_id   UNIQUE  Publicacao  [pub_id]    SBTREE  
TipoPublicacao.tpu_id   UNIQUE  TipoPublicacao  [tpu_id]    SBTREE
```

Is this an Orientdb bug?

Comment: Have you created the database with version 2.1 or 2.2? With Studio or console ?

Comment: Could you try with "dbURL": "remote:localhost/yourDb",
"dbType": "graph",
"dbUser": "admin",     
"dbPassword": "admin", 
"serverUser":"yourServerUser",
"serverPassword":"yourPasswordUser",
"dbAutoCreate": false,

Comment: ok, Alessandro, with serverUser and serverPassword the credential its ok BUT the selelects index: in _from and _to return -1, but if I execute the select in browser returns the @rid ok.

Answer (score 0):

try this as your command:

```
"command": "create edge PUBLICOU from (SELECT expand(rid) FROM index:Pesquisador.psq_id WHERE key = ${input.psq_id_from}) to   (SELECT expand(rid) FROM index:Producao.pro_id where key = ${input.pro_id_to})"
```

this should work because when you select from index the rid associated with the result record is in the property `rid`.

---

**Or even better** you can directly select from class instead of index:

```
create edge PUBLICOU from (SELECT FROM Pesquisador WHERE psq_id = ${input.psq_id_from}) to   (SELECT FROM Producao where pro_id = ${input.pro_id_to})
```

in this way it uses indexes as well.

[image: example]

Ivan

Comment: I tried use :index because the Orientdb suggested the use in log. There are about 10 milion edges to import. But the import with index: dont't execute, return Java Exception Error, then I use import within index:

Comment: I've edited my ans, in the first command I've added the `expand(rid)` in both select. Now it works.  Let me know

Comment: Thanks Ivan. It's ok now.